# Raycast goes backwards but the i code it to go forward

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

I try my best but my raycast still goes backwards every time - please I need help

Here's my code - basically the code shoots a raycast forward button to detected an enemy but instead the raycast goes the opposite way.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class milkscript: MonoBehaviour
{
    NavMeshAgent Agent;

    public Transform Point;

    public float raydistance = 40f;
    public float enemyview = 5f;
 
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        RaycastHit Hit;

        if(Physics.Raycast(Point.position,Point.position + Point.forward, out Hit, raydistance)) 
        {
            Debug.DrawRay(Point.position, Hit.transform.forward, Color.red);
            Debug.Log(Hit.transform.name);

            if(Hit.transform.tag == "chcolatemilk") 
            {
                ChasePlayer(Hit.transform);
            }
        }
    }

    public void ChasePlayer(Transform target)
    {
        Agent.SetDestination(target.position);
        transform.LookAt(target.position);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `DrawRay` uses the direction of the hit object, not the one you shoot your raycast in ...

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a combination of two issues

1. As mentioned your

   ```
   Debug.DrawRay(Point.position, Hit.transform.forward, Color.red);
   ```

   draws the ray in direction of `Hit.transform.forward` which is not the original direction you shoot your `Raycast` in
2. As a **direction** or the `Raycast` you are passing in

   ```
   Point.position + Point.forward
   ```

   which rather is a **position**.

   You want to pass in only `Point.forward` as a direction

So it should rather be

```
void Update()
{
    if(Physics.Raycast(Point.position, Point.forward, out var Hit, raydistance)) 
    {
        Debug.DrawLine(Point.position, Hit.transform.position, Color.red);
        // TODO: remove this later! Logging every frame is quite expensive!
        Debug.Log(Hit.transform.name);

        // prefer "CompareTag" over "=="! It is a) slightly faster and b)
        // instead of failing silently throws an error for typos and non-existent tags => better debugging live
        if(Hit.transform.CompareTag("chcolatemilk")) 
        {
            ChasePlayer(Hit.transform);
        }
    }
    Debug.DrawRay(Point.position, Point.forward, Color.green);
}
```